# Missing Mobile Status Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, mobile, uwp, .net-core

I am working with UWP .net core.
The app looks fine on desktop but on mobile there is a white stripe instead of the status bar.

I read a post about

```
StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundOpacity = 1;
```

But Visual Studio can't find "StatusBar".
What can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add *Windows Mobile Extension SDK* to your project as this is for Mobile device only.

Right click on your project, go

> *Add* > *Reference...*

When the *Reference Manager* window pops up, select

> *Universal Windows* > *Extensions*

on the left pane, and then pick the SDK with the version that you are targeting.

[image]